# Is there a canon explanation for the NASA Space Shuttle Enterprise name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-eu

Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105036/were-the-nx-class-starships-named-after-the-shuttles), is there a canon explanation for the Space Shuttle Enterprise's name?

Of course in real history, it was named for the USS Enterprise NCC-1701 seen in TOS.
However, since the Enterprise credits show the space shuttle, is there a different reason for the shuttle's name, or does TOS as a show actually exist in the Star Trek timeline?

Although [the suggested duplicate question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30594/why-did-flagship-starships-all-get-the-name-enterprise) is similar, it only answers why the starships were named Enterprise, not the NASA Space Shuttle.  Some comments do mention the real-life letter-writing campaign, but it doesn't specify if that event occurred within the Star Trek universe timeline.

Since I doubt there's an on-screen answer, I'll accept novels, comics, and any other EU material.

Comment: its most likely related to the the fact that enterprise has been a common name for navel vessels throughout history. however, we also have cross contamination throughout history from travelers from the future.

Comment: I just realized this question has a direct impact on rewriting my own life history. I was one of the people who signed the petitions to rename the first space shuttle _Enterprise_ after the good ol' NCC-1701. So if Trek ever gave a canon explanation, that rewrites that entire event and changes my life history in the Trek universe.

Comment: I believe this covers both in and out of universe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30594/why-did-flagship-starships-all-get-the-name-enterprise

Comment: @Mazura The only reference I see to the shuttle's name in that question is the letter-writing campaign to name it after the TOS ship.  I'm wondering if there is a different explanation for the name in the Star Trek timeline.  So far, Himarm has the most likely explanation.

Comment: This question kind of blew my mind.

Comment: @Austin - me too.  So can the characters of Star Trek go into the well-preserved archives and watch those old shows called Star Trek?

Comment: There is a long history of naming naval ships "Enterprise" - back to the HMS Enterprise in the 1700s. So even without the Star Trek connection, it would not be unreasonable to think that the shuttle could have come to have that name

Comment: All of the Space Shuttle orbiters were [named after antique naval sailing vessels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_orbiter#Fleet), and *Enterprise* OV-101 is no exception.  Although the name was chosen due to a letter writing campaign by Trekkies, it could just as easily have become the name without a Star Trek connection.  (Although, *Constitution*, another sailing vessel, was the front-runner, due to the 1976 bicentennial year.)

Comment: A genetically engineered Mexican/British/Indian man didn't conquer large areas of the planet in the 90s either.

Comment: Every fan should notice that Star Trek already was in an alternate universe back in 1966.  Some writers make historical errors that make Star Trek in an alternate universe.  The first divergence may have been thousands of years ago, and the two universes should have become more and more different.  But some mysterious unknown force pushed the two universes closer together (because some writers made accurate historical references).  Then the two universes diverged again because of another inaccurate historical reference.  And so on over and over again for centuries and millennia.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Memory-Alpha article on [OV-101 (Enterprise)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Enterprise_(OV-101)) says this in the Apocrypha section:

> The novel A Flag Full of Stars states that **she instead was named for the World War Two aircraft carrier because the brother of one of the engineers who worked on her died serving aboard said ship**, and that she was the last surviving space shuttle. She was refitted with impulse engines so she could participate in a parade of antique spacecraft celebrating the 300th anniversary of Apollo 11.

The Space Shuttle Enterprise is featured in Jonathan Archer's ready room, The refit USS Enterprise (Motion Picture), Benjamin Sisko's office, and in the alternate reality in Admiral Marcus's office.

It is clearly a part of the Star Trek history.

Comment: I completely missed the Apocrypha section of that entry earlier!  Looks like that's the closest canon info available.

Comment: Additionally, in one of the on-screen appearances of the image of Space Shuttle Enterprise, it appears next to the old sailing ship called Enterprise (an 18th century British vessel, if I'm not mistaken). Anyway, in-universe, the name "Enterprise" has a long and storied history.